# Generate multiple SUMIFS values over a range of cells

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sumifs

How can I repeat a sumif calculation for several items with two criteria? In the example below, I would like to sum "Amount Sold" based on *fruit* and *zone*:

```
                                            Input
```

| Fruit (Col A) | Misc (Col B) | Zone (Col C) | Amount Sold (Col D) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | blah | 1 | 5 |
| Pear | blah | 1 | 3 |
| Apple | blah | 1 | 4 |
| Apple | blah | 2 | 4 |
| Grape | blah | 2 | 4 |
| Pear | blah | 2 | 5 |

```
                              Desired Output (new sheet)
```

| Fruit | Zone | Amount Sold (lbs) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | 9 |
| Pear | 1 | 3 |
| Apple | 2 | 4 |
| Pear | 2 | 5 |
| Grape | 2 | 4 |

@Tanaike provided a perfect [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74303693/how-can-i-employ-google-apps-script-to-generate-multiple-sumif-values-over-a-ran/74310619?noredirect=1#comment131193835_74310619) when there is one criterion (*fruit*):

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your source sheet name.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set your destination sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  const values = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 4).getValues();
  const res = [...values.reduce((m, [a,,, b]) => m.set(a, m.has(a) ? m.get(a) + b : b), new Map())];
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
```

Any suggestions for adding a second criterion (e.g. *zone*)? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your showing sample input and output tables, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your source sheet name.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set your destination sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  const values = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 4).getValues();
  const res = [...values.reduce((m, [a, , c, d]) => {
    const k = a + c;
    return m.set(k, [a, c, m.has(k) ? m.get(k)[2] + d : d]);
  }, new Map()).values()];
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

- When this script is run, the source values are retrieved from the columns "A", "C", "D" of the source sheet. And, the values are converted and the converted values are put into the destination sheet.